# Getting callback when app is terminated (either by user or OS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I want to execute a piece of code when my iOS application is terminated (applicationWillTerminate doesn't work all the times).

The thing I want to do is whenever the app is terminated, I would like to cancel the local notifications and rely on push notifications as my local notification content is dynamic which is updated through silent notifications when app is in foreground or background.
P.S. The local notifications are triggered every 10 mins so can't rely on push notifications at all times.

Thanks.

Comment: applicationWillTerminate is correct.

Comment: applicationWillTerminate is not called when it is terminated by system or by user when in background..

Answer (score 0):

applicationWillTerminate is called when a user terminates the application without switching it to background mode.  So the user must have to double press on Home button and throws out the application to perform that applicationWillTerminate action.

Thanks, @Cristik for correcting.

```
Note:- applicationWillTerminate is not called when the user quits the app if the app supports background execution.
```

You can check this :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "terminated") {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let alertView: UIAlertController = UIAlertController.init(title: "Prompt", message: "App was terminated earlier", preferredStyle: .alert)
                let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .cancel) { (action:UIAlertAction) in
                    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "terminated")
                    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                }

                alertView.addAction(alertAction)

                self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }

        return true
}
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "terminated")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases the iOS terminates your app. For example if your app is in suspended mode (it's in background and codes are not executed) and there are memory pressure conditions in iOS device. In this case iOS starts to terminate apps based on its rules. Anyway, in this situation you won't receive any callback form OS about your app termination.

But there is a clue that may help you.
Now suppose you have enabled one of background mode capabilities in Xcode e.g. Bluetooth. In this situation (your app has been terminated by iOS before) if a related Bluetooth event occurs, the iOS runs your app again and tells your app that what was the reason of running your app by the OS. this information is stored in lunchOptions of this function:

```
application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil)
```

Using those information you can make decision what to do at the beginning of the app running.